# Abstracting dimensionality of arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

In Java, arrays of different dimensionalities have different types. So a method that takes `int[]` as a parameter cannot take `int[][]` or `int[][][]`. I have a lot of code where I create methods that are quite similar but for the dimensionality of the array. Is there a way to handle arrays of arbitrary dimensionality, and thus abstract out this common functionality?

Comment: Could you give an example of functionality that is independent of dimensionality of an array?

Comment: What is your code doing that having different dimensional arrays makes sense?

Comment: @Glitch Noise generation in 1D, 2D, and 3D.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: sum of array contents; zero the array; add two arrays; basically any operation on the array as a whole.  You need to meet an array processing language such as Fortran95 or (really fun!) APL.

Comment: Nope, there isn't a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to forego type safety, you can do it with a little recursion (no surprise here, right?) and reflection.

The idea is to write your method in a way that it recurses down until the array has only one dimension. Once you're at the single-dimension level, do the work; otherwise, call yourself recursively, and aggregate your findings from the prior levels if necessary.

Here is a quick demo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

class Main {
    public static int sumArray(Object array) {
            Class type = array.getClass();
            if (!type.isArray()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("array");
            }
            Class ct = type.getComponentType();
            int res = 0;
            int len = Array.getLength(array);
            if (ct.isArray()) {
                    for (int i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
                            res += sumArray(Array.get(array, i));
                    }
            } else {
                    for (int i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
                            res += Array.getInt(array, i);
                    }
            }
            return res;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            int[] a = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            int aa[][] = new int[][] {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
            int aaa[][][] = new int[][][]{{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}},{{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}}};
            System.out.println(sumArray(a));
            System.out.println(sumArray(aa));
            System.out.println(sumArray(aaa));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the closest thing you can do is make a few overload methods that take all the available dimensions of array and have each of them call a common method that has much of the logic.

```
public void method ( int [] i ) {  //1-d array
    //logic 
}

public void method ( int [][] i) {  //2-d array
     for (int [] j : i) {
         method(j);
     }
}

public void method ( int [][][] i) {   // 3-d array
    for ( int [][] j : i ) {
        method(j);
    }
}
```

...etc

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The long answer is sorry, but no. Due to how Java handles arrays, the two are fundamentally different types, and there isn't really any good way to handle arrays of any dimension with a single piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no! but you can do whatever you want with just linear arrays....think about it

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a multidimensional array by hiding its implementation in a class
(forgive or correct my Java syntax, I'm not a Java coder):

```
class MultidimensionalArray<Type> {

   // Implement N-dimensional 0-origin array of <Type>

   int[] dimensions;

   Type[] body;

   MultidimensionalArray(index1: int)
   {  dimensions=new int[1];
      dimensions[0]=index1;
      body=new Type[index1];
   }

   MultidimensionalArray(index1: int, index2: int)
   {  dimensions=new int[2];
      dimensions[0]=index1;
      dimensions[1]=index2;
      body=new Type[index1*index2];
   }

   MultidimensionalArray(int[] indexes)
   {  size=1;
      dimensions=indexes;
      for(int i=0;i<indexes.size();i++) size*=indexes[i];
      body=new Type[size];
   }

   Type Get(int index1) {
      assert dimensions.size()==1;
      return body[index1];
   }

   Type Get(int index1, int index2) {
      assert dimensions.size()==2;
      return body[index1*dimensions[0]+index2];
   }

   Type Get(int[] indexes) {
      int index=indexes[0];
      assert dimensions.size()==indexes.size();
      for (int i=0;i<indexes.size();i++) index=index*dimensions[i]+indexes[i+1];
      return body[index];
   }

   void Put(int index1, Type v) {
      assert dimensions.size()==1;
      body[index1]=v;
   }

   void Put(int index1, int index2, Type v) {
      assert dimensions.size()==2;
      body[index1*dimensions[0]+index2]=v;
   }

   void Put(int[] indexes, Type v) {
      int index=indexes[0];
      assert dimensions.size()==indexes.size();
      for (int i=0;i<indexes.size();i++) index=index*dimensions[i]+indexes[i+1];
      body[index]=v;
   }

}
```

You initialize this by calling its consructor, and accessing an element by passing
in an integer array as the index set.  A little clumsy but works:

```
int[] mydimensions={2,3,5};
MyArray MultidimensionalArray<int>=new MultidimensionalArray(mydimensions);
... 
int[] indexset={1,2,4};
MyArray.Put(indexset,22);
...
indexset = {0,1,3};
...  MyArray.Get(indexset) ...
```

I added convenience functions for 1D and 2D arrays that don't require index sets, but rather use individual arguments as indexes.   Easily generalized to arrays of dimension K. You could also add functions to create indexsets of varying sizes.

All this comes at a price of some overhead.

Comment: Caveat: In Java, you can't have arrays of generics. That is, you can't make a `new Type[index1]`.

Comment: All that work for generics and you can't do that?  Ah well; now you know why I'm not a Java programmer.    OK, so you can build a special class for each type you want. (Ick).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "probably no".  As other answers have pointed out array types with different dimensionalities are not assignment compatible.  However, there is a possible way out.

The types `int[]` `int[][]` and `int[][][]` are all subtypes of `Object`.  And (for example) an `int[][]` is actually an array of `int[]` instances.  So *for some calculations* it might be possible to do something like this:

```
public void calc(Object array) {
    if (array instanceof int[]) {
        calc((int[]) array);
    } else if (array instanceof int[][]) {
        for (a int[] : (int[][]) array) {
            calc(a);
        }
    } else if (array instanceof int[][][]) {
        for (a int[][] : (int[][][]) array) {
            for (a2 int[] : a) {
                calc(a2);
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(...);  // or something more appropriate
    }
}

public void calc (int[] array) {
    // do the calculation
}
```

Caveats:

- this only works if the calculation works this way,
- you have to repeat this ugly boilerplate for each method, and
- the boilerplate could actually be worse than having three separate methods.

Now, depending on the calculation (and performance requirements), you may be able to generalize the code by doing the calculation in a object which can be passed to a generalized "apply to all elements" method; e.g.

```
public interface Calc {
    public void calc(int i);
}

... 

public void doCalc(Object array, Calc calculator) {
    // as above
}

public void doCalc(int[] array, Calc calculator) {
    for (int i : array) {
        calculator.calc(i);
    }
}
```

... but there's still a lot of boilerplate ... and you'd take a performance hit.